# Categories missing from API

Tags: api, categories, eventbrite

According to the Eventbrite API documentation (http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/user-owned-events/), categories should be returned as part of the response. However, this is not working. I have set the categories for all the events of the owner, but these values are not being returned.

Anyone know as to why i'm not able to see this value? am I missing any aditional configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Eventbrite has recently changed the event categories, and when this happened it unfortunately had a negative effect on the categories returned via the API. The issue is currently being worked on and hopefully will be resolved soon.